# I've only uploaded eclipse-workspace/ProjectName/src/packageName/* on github, how can I make it less dirty?

Tags: eclipse, github

I'm sorry for the title, but that's the easiest way I could describe it.

So I didn't know how to use eclipse integrated git tool, so during last few weeks, I worked with eclipse on a project and didn't git push from there. Instead, i copied every file in *eclipse-workspace/ProjectName/src/packageName* in another folder which I remoted with my git and stuff, and did the usuals `git add/merge/push`

So basically, my github project is only the content of this file and a README, and I realize that it's really messy. How could I change that and make it right ? Is it already too late and should I just create a new project from eclipse git tool or can I rectify it ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easier to create a new project locally, and make sure its content looks OK for you.

Clone the repo and empty its content.
Recreate your project with your new organization, add, commit and push back.